# High memory usage from "git status -z -u"?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, git

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. Recently I often find one or two "`git status -z -u`" process that each takes more than 5GB of memory. So I try to figure out what's going wrong. pstree gives me some output like this:

```
systemd──lightdm──lightdm──upstart──2*[git]
```

Apparently upstart started these git processes. So I try to list all jobs of upstart

```
$ initctl list
indicator-application start/running, process 2364
unicast-local-avahi stop/waiting
update-notifier-crash stop/waiting
upstart-udev-bridge start/running, process 1773
update-notifier-hp-firmware stop/waiting
xsession-init stop/waiting
dbus start/running, process 1774
no-pinentry-gnome3 stop/waiting
update-notifier-cds stop/waiting
gnome-keyring-ssh stop/waiting
gnome-session (Unity) start/running, process 2007
ssh-agent stop/waiting
unity7 start/running, process 2132
upstart-dbus-session-bridge start/running, process 1812
gpg-agent start/running
indicator-messages start/running, process 2343
logrotate stop/waiting
indicator-bluetooth start/running, process 2344
unity-panel-service start/running, process 2009
hud start/running, process 1969
im-config start/running
unity-gtk-module stop/waiting
session-migration stop/waiting
upstart-dbus-system-bridge start/running, process 1811
at-spi2-registryd start/running, process 1999
indicator-power start/running, process 2345
update-notifier-release stop/waiting
indicator-datetime start/running, process 2346
indicator-keyboard start/running, process 2347
unity-settings-daemon start/running, process 1971
indicator-sound start/running, process 2348
upstart-file-bridge start/running, process 1817
bamfdaemon start/running, process 1828
gnome-keyring stop/waiting
window-stack-bridge start/running, process 1786
indicator-printers start/running, process 2349
re-exec stop/waiting
upstart-event-bridge stop/waiting
unity-panel-service-lockscreen stop/waiting
indicator-session start/running, process 2350
```

and also

```
$ initctl status
unity7 start/running, process 2132
```

I didn't see anything that related to these git processes. Can anyone give me some hints of what's going wrong and how should I locate my problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Is it a really large git project?

Comment: What are the full parameters of the `git` commands?  Also, from the `git-status` manual - "`-u` [...] Because it takes extra work to find untracked files in the filesystem, this mode may take some time in a large working tree".  If these are being run on a large directory tree or on a tree with unexpected mounts to other filesystems, that might be why they are taking unexpectedly large piles of time and resources.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Just `git status -z -u`. The problem is that I don't know which process called `git status`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DopeGhoti is correct in the comments. In my case, it turns out to be the problem of Visual Studio Code working on dictionary from mounted network locations. After disable the git in Visual Studio Code, the problem is gone.